# Como puedo usar una variable para alojar el nombre de un include php

Tags: php

Buen día,

Me gustaría saber si es posible almacenar en una variable el nombre del fichero que quiero incluir en la pagina

```
//Quiero hacer algo así
$include = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].'\nes\clases/Config.php';
include_once($include);
//Para no hacer esto y tener que cambiar la ruta cuando subo la aplicación al servidor
include_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\nes\clases/Config.php');
```

Comment: Intentastes hacerlo de esa forma? O te salio un error

Comment: Si lo intente y me arrojo este error: 
Warning: include_once(localhost\nes\clases/Config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\nes\admin\index.php on line 15

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'localhost\nes\clases/Config.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\nes\admin\index.php on line 15

Comment: Lo raro es que si yo ingreso directamente en el navegador a la ruta localhost\nes\clases/Config.php si encuentra en archivo, no se si esto pasa por que se esta corriendo localmente

Answer (score 3):

Primero: es conveniente que uses solo un separador de carpeta, puedes usar la constante [DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR](https://www.php.net/manual/es/dir.constants.php), que se adapta de acuerdo al sistema operativo, por ejemplo `\` para Windows y `/` para Linux/MAC.

Normalmente yo uso diagonal "normal" `/` y me ha funcionado tanto en Windows como en Linux.

Opciones:

```
// Usando la constante
$archivo = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'nes' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'clases' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Config.php';
// Hacerlo directamente
$archivo = '/nes/clases/Config.php';
```

Segundo: `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]` te devuelve el nombre del servidor (localhost) y no la carpeta donde está el proyecto (c:/xampp/htdocs), por lo tanto, `include` no encuentra el archivo a cargar.

Si todas las peticiones pasan por un archivo específico, como `index.php` en la carpeta raíz, o tienes un archivo que siempre debes incluir como configuración, functiones comunes, etc., ahí puedes definir una constante para usar en todo el proyecto:

```
// En index.php garantizas que sea la carpeta raíz
define('BASE_DIR', __DIR__); // c:\xampp\htdocs
// Para incluir un archivo, en cualquier parte de tu proyecto:
include_once BASE_DIR . '/nes/clases/Config.php';
```

Si deseas "normalizar" el contenido de la constante, puedes eliminar unidad de disco (c:) y remplazar las diagonales invertidas por normales usando [str_ireplace()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-ireplace)

```
// No es necesario definir estas variables, se pueden enviar como parámetro
// Solo las coloco para que se vea más claro qué se va a modificar
$buscar = ['c:', '\\'];
$remplazar = ['', '/'];
$baseDir = str_ireplace($buscar, $remplazar, __DIR__);
define(BASE_DIR, $baseDir); //  /xampp/htdocs
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información proporcionada